# comparing values in separate spreadsheets

Tags: excel, compare

I have two separate spreadsheet, one with our records and one with a customers records, is there a formula to compare columns from each one to find all of the duplicate numbers to make sure both of our records match up?

Answer (score 0):

create another column that is =if(column1 = column 2,1,0). If they are equal, than that column will read 1. Otherwise will read 0.